# VBA - Concatenar nome impressão automática PDF mala direta

Tags: vba, excel-vba, impressão, merge, microsoft-word

Preciso imprimir PDFs de mala direta onde o nome será composto por 2 informações do arquivo.
Alguém saberia me dizer como juntar 2 campos para setar a impressão?

Preciso incluir um segundo campo como por ex, numero do ticket pra corrigir um problema de duplicidade.

Campo:

`nomeArquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Nome_Completo").Value`

código inteiro:

```
Sub SalvarComoPDF()

Dim qtde As Integer
Dim nomeArquivo As String
Dim registro As Integer

'Set Mail Merge in the first register
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord

'Mail Merge Count
qtde = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
'arquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.FieldNames(1).Name

'For to exportToPDF all registers
    For registro = 1 To qtde

      nomeArquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Nome_Completo").Value

      ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "D:\Users\roseli_monteiro-ran\Downloads\Teste imp\" & nomeArquivo & ".pdf" _
    , ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
    Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
    CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
      BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

      ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
        
Next registro
    
End
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Na variavel nome do arquivo basta juntar a outra string.

onde está

```
nomeArquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Nome_Completo").Value
```

deverás alterar para

```
nomeArquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Nome_Completo").Value & SEGUNDO _VALOR_QUE_QUERES_ADICIONAR
```

Comment: Não cumprimente e não agradeça nas publicações. Caso deseje ajudar você pode editar as publicações removendo cumprimentos, agradecimento e assinaturas .

Answer (score -2):

Quando tento juntar dois campos no nome do arquivo e um deles é alfa numérico, a macro não roda.
Alguém saberia o que pode ser?

nomeArquivo = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Nome").Value & " - " & ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Numero_ticket").Value